# PHP - Can I make this if else into a cleaner snippet like an array and loop?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, if-statement

```
<?
///////////////////////
///////////////////////
$OriginalUrlToDisplay=strtok($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'?');
$buttonTypeForColours="radio";
///////////////////////
///////////////////////
?>
<form>
<input type="<?=$buttonTypeForColours ?>" name="colourChoice[]" <? if($_GET["filter"]=="White"){?> onclick="location.href='<?=$OriginalUrlToDisplay?>'" checked="checked" <? } else {?> onclick="location.href='?filter=White'"<? } ?>/> <img src="http://www.gc-cdn.com/mobile/white.png" /> White<br />
<input type="<?=$buttonTypeForColours ?>" name="colourChoice[]" <? if($_GET["filter"]=="Black"){?> onclick="location.href='<?=$OriginalUrlToDisplay?>'" checked="checked" <? } else {?> onclick="location.href='?filter=Black'"<? } ?>/> <img src="http://www.gc-cdn.com/mobile/black.png" /> Black<br />
</form>
```

Is there a cleaner way to write this. There are over 40 colours. I know it is not really data intensive but it is difficult to read and manage.

Comment: have you tried with a function?

Comment: Agreed ^, just use a simple loop to generate the HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily loop it like this:

```
<?php

$colors = array("White", "Black", "Green", "...");
foreach ($colors as $color) {
    echo '<input type="', $buttonTypeForColours, '" name="colourChoice[]"',
         $_GET["filter"] == $color
             ? 'onclick="location.href=\'?\'" checked="checked"' 
             : 'onclick="location.href=\'?filter=' . $color . '\'"',
         ' /><img src="http://www.gc-cdn.com/mobile/', strtolower($color), '.png" /> ', $color, '<br />'
         ;
}

?>
```

It is looping trough all the possible colors specified in `$colors` and then displays the right output by using a in-string [ternary operator.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

You could also easily do a non-casesensitive comparison by changing

```
$_GET["filter"] == $color
```

to

```
strcasecmp($_GET["filter"], $color) === 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like this;

```
<form>
<?php
$colours = array('black', 'white', 'yellow', 'green', '...');
foreach($colours as $colour):
    $url = $_GET['filter'] == $colour || $_GET['filter'] == ucfirst($colour) ? $OriginalUrlToDisplay : '?filter='. ucfirst($colour);
?>
    <input type="<?php echo $buttonTypeForColours; ?>" name="colourChoice[]" onclick="location.href='<?php echo $url; ?>'" checked="checked" /> <img src="http://www.gc-cdn.com/mobile/white.png" /> White<br />
<?php 
endforeach;
?>
</form>
```

BTW; if you use a radio button, do not append [] to the name (unless you really want to use an array with a single element in php). Normally you'd only use that notation for checkboxes where multiple options are allowed.

Note: I would NOT advice you to use short echo statement (`<?="print this" ?>`) as it is not supported by default on every machine. Furthermore it hardly improves readability (although this is personal)

Comment: For current stable PHP 5.4 and future versions, it (`<?=`) *is* enabled per default.

Answer (score -1):

How about breaking in multiple lines and using PHP's alternative sintax? like:

```
<?php if(...): ?>
    <sometag></sometag>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I don't even know what this means. -1

Comment: The [php alternative sintax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) proved to be very helpful to me, when writting better looking views. I just thought it could help you too.